# qemu удаление image

Tags: qemu

Создал qemu image:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 image.iso 10G
```

А как его удалить? Он место на диске занимает

Comment: Ткнуть правой кнопкой мыши по этому файлу и выбрать пункт "Удалить"?

Comment: Оно не делало никаких новых файлов.

Comment: qemu-img create именно тем и занимается, что создаёт новые файлы в тех путях, которые вы указываете (image.iso)

Answer (score 0):

При запуске этой команды в текущей директории создается файл `image.iso`, чтобы его удалить, просто выполните команду:

```bash
rm image.iso
```